# VBA skipping loop?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is determining if a cell in the row contains the word "Done". If it does then the row is copied to another sheet labled "Log" and removed from the list.
Why might the following loop be skipping some rows that are marked "Done"?

```
Sub LogAndDelete()

Dim r As Integer
Dim Emptyrow As Integer
r = 1
For r = 5 To 70
    If Cells(r, 15) = "Done" Then
        'copying the row marked "Done"
        rng = Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 7))

        'determining the next empty row on log sheet
        Emptyrow = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Log").Range("A:A")) + 1

        'Pasting onto log sheet
        Range(Worksheets("Log").Cells(Emptyrow, 2), Worksheets("Log").Cells(Emptyrow, 8)) _
        = rng

        'Adding the date removed from log sheet in column A
        Worksheets("Log").Cells(Emptyrow, 1) = Date

        'Removing row marked "done" from list
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 10)).ClearContents
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: A tip, always use a convention like r c for row column or row, col it makes code a lot more readable by others.

Comment: Aye Aye Aye, `CountA` to find the next available row? I know you are using `Worksheets("Log").Cells(Emptyrow, 1) = Date` but what if few cells are blank in Col A (got deleted by chance)? To get the last row, use [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)  Also how is `rng` declared?

Comment: I was having the same issue even before I added the logging feature to the loop. So it can't be anything to do the countA

Comment: I know :) My above comment was to make it better :)

Comment: Oh Haha didn't see the link. Thanks! For my case, CountA is working and I think the risk of blanks is not something to be concerned about. But thank you! 
`With Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With`
This works great too!

Comment: What should rng be Dimentioned as?

Comment: Range :) Also, if you do more complex code in the future, you may want to consider using a For Each loop instead of your current numerical substitution loop with r.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your else case. You are already ignoring that row by going into the else block. and your loop code takes care of incrementing. So your code is basically

```
If Cells(r, 15) = "Done" Then
    'process done row
Else
    'skip two rows.
End If
```

I think you should omit your else block and let the loop structure iterate over r.

```
'remove this part
Else
    r = r + 1
```

Comment: Yup! you're right. Taking out that 2 row skip was right. Don't know why i overlooked that. Thank you! Omit: `Else  r = r + 1`

Comment: Its pretty easy to skip rows when doing things conditionally I'd be lying if I said I've never done that.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering incrementing i inside a For loop could be the issue. Haven't tested it though.

comment out following line and test.

```
    i = i + 1
```